# How do I create a new branch based on an existing Git hub branch? (Please read - tried the beginners guide)

Tags: git, branch, terminal, github, git-branch

I have a master branch and would like to create a new branch based on it, and then switch to the new branch.

I'm very very new to coda/github/terminal so I don't even know if my syntax is correct. here's what I typed in, letter for letter, with the exception of the branch names which are placeholders:

> git checkout -b $newbranchname $oldbranchname

This was the suggested format based on the github cheatsheet seen here: http://bit.ly/WXRGN

unfortunately I get this error message: fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Please help, I really have no idea what's going on. Do I need to be pointing to a directory or something in the branch name? Any info is much appreciated

Comment: Can you tell me, in which directory you executed this command? And please indent your code by 4 spaces in order to let the syntax highlighter do it's work.

Comment: I prefer to leave indents for code formatting and the > operator to mark unstyled text such as this

Comment: Have you tried a `git status` to make sure that you are in a repository?

Comment: i tried git status and still get 'fatal: not a git repository' error. how do i go about fixing this?

Comment: Are you running your commands in the same directory as the `.git` folder of your project?

Comment: Did you correctly `init` the repo? is it as clone?

Answer (score 2):

Use `cd` to move into the directory, where your repo is.

Like

```
$ ls
foo bar baz myRepo
$ cd myRepo
$ ls -a
src README make .git
```

The `.git` entry shows you, that there's a repository in this directory. You can only issue a git command for the repo from this directory or any subdirectories.